# EWS Managed API: Setup user email alias

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, office365, exchangewebservices

I am looking into possibility to create or delete email aliases for user emails in Office 365 through EWS Managed API.
It can be easily done through UI: https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Add-an-email-alias-to-a-user-account-cd25a91a-eb1a-4ed7-be94-5517fb5113c2, but unfortunately, I haven't found any methods in Exchange Web Services API to do this.

Does anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: There are quite some features that are not yet available in EWS, although they are easily accomplished via GUI. EWS is mostly for handling data (mail/calendar), not for metadata (users/profiles/permissions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EWS does not support manipulating the user. You would want to investigate using Remote Powershell and the mailbox-related cmdlets.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like PowerShell is the right tool for this. Thanks!